# how to check whether user after login has submitted the form one , if yes again if he login he should redirect to form 2 not one again in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I have an app where user login and after he logins he get redirect to dashboard where appears a form and user fill the form , once user fill the form he redirect to next page where it shows the progress of the form. So if user login again he should automatically redirect to the progress page he should not get the form page again if he has filled it .
Can any one suggest me how to achieve these.

```
views.py 

def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = AccountProfile()
        post.user = request.user
        post.name = request.POST['name']
        post.email = request.POST['email']
        post.mobile = request.POST['mobile']
        post.date = request.POST['date']
        post.sex = request.POST['sex']
        post.save()
        return render (request,'posts/dashboard-post-a-job.html')
```

These is the views where user get redirect after login and fill form.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the progress in the database. If you need to check for only one form, then add a new column in `AccountProfile` model.

> models.py

```
class AccountProfile(models.Model):
    ...

    form1_submitted = models.BooleanField()
```

Then, once the form is submitted, you can update this field.

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = AccountProfile()
        post.user = request.user
        post.name = request.POST['name']
        post.email = request.POST['email']
        post.mobile = request.POST['mobile']
        post.date = request.POST['date']
        post.sex = request.POST['sex']
        post.form1_submitted = True  # save the progress
        post.save()
        return render (request,'posts/dashboard-post-a-job.html')
```

Now, the progress page can check the value of this field and render the form accordingly.